# No connection made with Driver after initiating Electron application in selenium C#, with the code below

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, electron

**Issue**:

> Message:  OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Cannot start the driver
> service on http://localhost:62908/ TearDown :
> System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.
>
> Stack Trace:  DriverService.Start()
> DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
> WebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2
> parameters) WebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
> WebDriver.ctor(ICommandExecutor executor, ICapabilities capabilities)
> ChromiumDriver.ctor(ChromiumDriverService service, ChromiumOptions
> options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
> ChromeDriver.ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options,
> TimeSpan commandTimeout) ChromeDriver.ctor(ChromeDriverService
> service, ChromeOptions options) Selenium_Demo.Start_Browser() line 24
> --TearDown Selenium_Demo.Close_Browser() line 50
>
> Standard Output:  No connection could be made because the target
> machine actively refused it. No connection could be made because the
> target machine actively refused it. No connection could be made
> because the target machine actively refused it. No connection could be
> made because the target machine actively refused it. No connection
> could be made because the target machine actively refused it. No
> connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
> it. No connection could be made because the target machine actively
> refused it. No connection could be made because the target machine
> actively refused it. No connection could be made because the target
> machine actively refused it. No connection could be made because the
> target machine actively refused it.

**Code:**

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;

namespace Selenium_Demo
{
    class Selenium_Demo
    {

        IWebDriver driver;

        [SetUp]
        public void Start_Browser()
        {

            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            ChromeDriverService chromeService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\\selenium\\chromedriver_win32v\\chromedriver.exe",
         @"C:\\Program Files\\Electronapp.exe");

            driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeService, options);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test()
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(6000);

            Console.WriteLine("Test Passed");
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void Close_Browser()
        {
            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```